# How do I tell pandas not to parse dates from excel(leave the string as is)? I tried every option of dytpe and converters but it still does not work

Tags: python, pandas, excel, string, date

This is how my excel file looks:

| SNo | Date |
| 1 | 28/2/2024|
| 2 |  29/2/2024|
|3 | 1/3/2024|

etc

So when I read this data into pandas, I want this date string to be
retained as in the pandas dataframe. I don't want pandas to do any modifications
on it, like for eg convert to 2024-2-28

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx')

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   sno       date
0    1 2024-02-28
1    2 2024-02-29
2    3 2024-03-01
3    4 2024-03-02
4    5 2024-03-03
5    6 2024-03-04
6    7 2024-03-05
7    8 2024-03-06
8    9 2024-03-07
9   10 2024-03-08

In [4]: df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', dtype=object)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  sno       date
0   1 2024-02-28
1   2 2024-02-29
2   3 2024-03-01
3   4 2024-03-02
4   5 2024-03-03
5   6 2024-03-04
6   7 2024-03-05
7   8 2024-03-06
8   9 2024-03-07
9  10 2024-03-08

In [6]: df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', dtype=string)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', dtype=string)

NameError: name 'string' is not defined

In [7]: df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', dtype=str)

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  sno                 date
0   1  2024-02-28 00:00:00
1   2  2024-02-29 00:00:00
2   3  2024-03-01 00:00:00
3   4  2024-03-02 00:00:00
4   5  2024-03-03 00:00:00
5   6  2024-03-04 00:00:00
6   7  2024-03-05 00:00:00
7   8  2024-03-06 00:00:00
8   9  2024-03-07 00:00:00
9  10  2024-03-08 00:00:00

In [9]: df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', dtype="string")

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  sno                 date
0   1  2024-02-28 00:00:00
1   2  2024-02-29 00:00:00
2   3  2024-03-01 00:00:00
3   4  2024-03-02 00:00:00
4   5  2024-03-03 00:00:00
5   6  2024-03-04 00:00:00
6   7  2024-03-05 00:00:00
7   8  2024-03-06 00:00:00
8   9  2024-03-07 00:00:00
9  10  2024-03-08 00:00:00

In [11]: df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', dtype=object, parse_dates=False)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  sno       date
0   1 2024-02-28
1   2 2024-02-29
2   3 2024-03-01
3   4 2024-03-02
4   5 2024-03-03
5   6 2024-03-04
6   7 2024-03-05
7   8 2024-03-06
8   9 2024-03-07
9  10 2024-03-08

In [13]: df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', converters = {'date': str})

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   sno                 date
0    1  2024-02-28 00:00:00
1    2  2024-02-29 00:00:00
2    3  2024-03-01 00:00:00
3    4  2024-03-02 00:00:00
4    5  2024-03-03 00:00:00
5    6  2024-03-04 00:00:00
6    7  2024-03-05 00:00:00
7    8  2024-03-06 00:00:00
8    9  2024-03-07 00:00:00
9   10  2024-03-08 00:00:00
```

I tried every value of the parameter dtype and also tried using converters.

Comment: I believe your data in excel already has a "datetime" dtype, with a custom format, not a string dtype. So when importing you either get a "datetime" dtype or convert it to string.

Comment: Are the dates stored as dates or text in Excel? Pandas probably preserves whatever format is there already. So you may need to import as a date, then convert to string in the format you want.